# Enable CORS requests on Java JAX-RS API on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, jax-rs

I have a Java web application where I am sending some requests from jQuery to a Rest API configured with JAX-RS, on my local machine it is working perfectly, but after deploying it on Heroku, it gives me an error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at...
```

Particularly, I am sending a POST request from jQuery to this endpoint.

I have configured the CORS filter for my application as well which caused it to work on my local machine (before doing this, the app was giving me the same error on my local machine). Anyway here is how I configured it

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Location, origin, content-type, accept, authorization, enctype, content-disposition");
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location");
    responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
}
```

}

I have also tried to add these headers to the Response object that I am giving back as a response to the request, but with no luck.

I believe it must be some Heroku thing, but I am not sure.

Any help would be apperciated.

Comment: this is some configuration I've used on a non-Java app. Maybe you can try to match it? https://gist.github.com/jkutner/be4f0f4d89f5ba65755a3750ec79863e

Comment: thanks for the reply, I fixed it by altering versions of some dependencies in my pom.xml. Java is hella weird sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Normal Filter:

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

  private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
  private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
  private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
  private static final String ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS = "Access-Control-Expose-Headers";
  private static final String ALL = "*";
  private static final String ALLOWED_METHODS = "GET";
  private static final String ALLOWED_HEADERS =
      "origin, content-type, accept, Authorization, x-requested-with";
  private static final String EXPOSE_HEADERS = "TEST";

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse sresponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    sresponse.setHeader(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, ALL);
    sresponse.setHeader(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, ALLOWED_METHODS);
    sresponse.setHeader(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, ALLOWED_HEADERS);
    sresponse.setHeader(ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, EXPOSE_HEADERS);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

  public void destroy() {}
}
```